# What does App Inbox message in Marketing Cloud do?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I'm struggling to understand the concept of App Inbox message type within Marketing Cloud's Mobile Studio. Can someone explain what this does (thats not from the Salesforce documentation). Some use cases would be appreciated it.

From what I read, it sounds like you could have an inbox within your app... and this message can deliver messages into that inbox, unlike a normal push notification this will be persistent and be stored within that inbox? What I don't understand is does it *have* to link to a CloudPage or could it push to a deep-link within the app?

Answer (score 2):

Correct. In-App inboxes are where messages can be stored by the app. This is often used in-conjunction with App Notifications - where the inbox is used as a history of notifications that the user can review at a later date.
Use cases could include Marketing Vouchers, Sale/Promo/Alert info, competitions & terms, etc.
For example, the StackExchange mobile app has in "inbox" where your recent notifications are stored - this allows you to view a history of all received notifications/messages.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Cameron, could you explain why a Cloud Page has to be used for that and how it has to be configured? Help seems to be not clear about that to me as it is only stated that "the Cloud Page" has to be used https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_app_inbox_messaging.htm&type=5 Maybe you already used that feature and could clarify?

Comment: Hi @BjörnSchubert i too have same question that why is  Cloud Page have to be required for an Inbox Message? In the documentation i havent find even how to deeplink within the app.